# Copy folder to multiple (similar) locations simultaneously

Tags: centos, ssh, file-copy, cpanel

I have around 90 websites I need a plugin installed on (wordpress) and I was wondering if there's a way to copy the plugin folder to all of them in a single run (i.e., simultaneously / in parallel). 
These are all on the same cPanel so same path, except for the domain name.

The paths look like this:

- `/home/user/site1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/`
- `/home/user/site2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/`

and so on.

I obviously tried the following, but it takes a lot of time :)

```
scp -r /path/to/local/dir /home/user/site1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all destination folders are /wp-content/plugins/, then you could iterate using find command, for example like this (assuming you are using bash and directory names have no 'space'):

```
for dir in $(find /home/user -name wp-content); do
  [ -d ${dir}/plugins ] && scp -r /path/to/local/dir ${dir}/plugins/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop which will do the job!

```
for i in {1..90}
do
 # your-unix-command-here
 # scp -r /path/to/local/dir /home/user/site$i/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ 
 echo $i
done
```